# Error: NA in probability vector when using the estR0() function from the R0 package

Tags: r, runtime-error

Trying to find the reproduction number given some data using the R0 package, however I'm having trouble at the very end when using the estimation function. Here is what I do:

```
## Get the incidence data
test <- c(`2020-01-22` = 0L, `2020-01-23` = 0L, `2020-01-24` = 0L, `2020-01-25` = 0L, 
`2020-01-26` = 0L, `2020-01-27` = 0L, `2020-01-28` = 0L, `2020-01-29` = 0L, 
`2020-01-30` = 0L, `2020-01-31` = 0L, `2020-02-01` = 0L, `2020-02-02` = 0L, 
`2020-02-03` = 0L, `2020-02-04` = 0L, `2020-02-05` = 0L, `2020-02-06` = 0L, 
`2020-02-07` = 0L, `2020-02-08` = 0L, `2020-02-09` = 0L, `2020-02-10` = 0L, 
`2020-02-11` = 0L, `2020-02-12` = 0L, `2020-02-13` = 0L, `2020-02-14` = 0L, 
`2020-02-15` = 0L, `2020-02-16` = 0L, `2020-02-17` = 0L, `2020-02-18` = 0L, 
`2020-02-19` = 0L, `2020-02-20` = 0L, `2020-02-21` = 0L, `2020-02-22` = 0L, 
`2020-02-23` = 0L, `2020-02-24` = 0L, `2020-02-25` = 0L, `2020-02-26` = 0L, 
`2020-02-27` = 0L, `2020-02-28` = 1L, `2020-02-29` = 3L, `2020-03-01` = 1L, 
`2020-03-02` = 0L, `2020-03-03` = 0L, `2020-03-04` = 0L, `2020-03-05` = 0L, 
`2020-03-06` = 1L, `2020-03-07` = 0L, `2020-03-08` = 1L, `2020-03-09` = 0L, 
`2020-03-10` = 0L, `2020-03-11` = 1L, `2020-03-12` = 4L, `2020-03-13` = 0L, 
`2020-03-14` = 14L, `2020-03-15` = 15L, `2020-03-16` = 12L, `2020-03-17` = 29L, 
`2020-03-18` = 11L, `2020-03-19` = 25L, `2020-03-20` = 46L, `2020-03-21` = 39L, 
`2020-03-22` = 48L, `2020-03-23` = 65L, `2020-03-24` = 51L, `2020-03-25` = 38L, 
`2020-03-26` = 70L, `2020-03-27` = 110L, `2020-03-28` = 132L, 
`2020-03-29` = 131L, `2020-03-30` = 145L, `2020-03-31` = 101L
)

## Make a time generation distribution (these parameters were found from the disease I'm studying)
d <- generation.time("gamma", c(4.243319, 2.488787))

## Calculate R0
estR0 <- estimate.R(
  epid = test,
  GT = d,
  begin = 45,
  end = 70,
  methods = c("EG", "ML", "TD", "AR", "SB"),
  pop.size = 126200000,
  nsim = 1000
)
```

This produces an error and several warnings:

```
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Error in rmultinom(nsim, epid$incid[s] - import[s], p[1:s, s]) : 
  NA in probability vector
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In est.R0.TD(epid = c(`2020-01-22` = 0L, `2020-01-23` = 0L, `2020-01-24` = 0L,  :
  Simulations may take several minutes.
2: In est.R0.TD(epid = c(`2020-01-22` = 0L, `2020-01-23` = 0L, `2020-01-24` = 0L,  :
  Gap in epidemic curve is longer than the generation interval. Consider using a different GT distribution (maybe with "truncate= 37 " (length of longest gap)).
3: In est.R0.TD(epid = c(`2020-01-22` = 0L, `2020-01-23` = 0L, `2020-01-24` = 0L,  :
  Using initial incidence as initial number of cases.
```

Switching around the start/end intervals, population and simulation parameters didn't help. What is going wrong during the rmultinom() step?

Comment: The code is triggering an error for the "TD" method. You'll also find that the "SB" method fails. I'm not exactly sure why, but if these are not important to you, then omit those two methods in the call.

Comment: Yes this makes it work for the particular interval in the question, although it is still not clear why the other methods aren't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the help page of `est.R0.TD`, the "begin" and "end" arguments are not actually used.

Try this:

```
test2 <- test[45:70]

estimate.R(
  epid = test2,
  GT = d,
  methods = c("EG", "ML", "TD", "AR", "SB"),  
  pop.size = 126200000,
  nsim = 1000
)

estR0
Reproduction number estimate using  Exponential Growth  method.
R :  2.179363[ 2.074176 , 2.291742 ]

Reproduction number estimate using  Maximum Likelihood  method.
R :  1.945082[ 1.778461 , 2.121745 ]

Reproduction number estimate using  Attack Rate  method.
R :  1.000004[ 1.000004 , 1.000005 ]

Reproduction number estimate using  Time-Dependent  method.
3.294674 0 4.463411 0 0 5.772949 5.059529 0 2.858751 2.361108 ...

Reproduction number estimate using  Sequential Bayesian  method.
```